# Unable to connect GCM using putty

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have created GCM and now trying to connect the same using putty. I created public key and private key using puttygen utility. Then I added the public key to SSH Key tab in metadata as :
Now when i try to connect using putty and private key file i get error - server refused our key

Answer (score 1):

When using putty you don't need to add anything in the Cloud console. You just need to use puttygen to generate a private key and then choose that key when authenticating in putty; you can add it on the Auth tab and then save it in a profile before logging into the machine.